# How to set the GridLayoutManager for the RecyclerView Having the Parent & Child View differently

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am Trying to display the my Custom List of objects using the `RecyclerView`. In the `RecyclerView` there is Two Sections one is for Parent and another one is Child(in this section I want to display the list).For this I am extending my Custom Adapter with the `ExpandableRecyclerAdapter`.It is working fine when setting the `GridLayoutManger` to the `Recyclerview` with the Span count of 1. But when setting the `spanCount` to 2 the Child Views are also reflecting and the `UI` is displaying Improper.Actually I want to show the List is Like mentioned in the below Screen Shot.
Red color indicates the Parent and Blue indicates the Child list. I want to display them as shown below screen shot.Please can anyone Help me.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: simple make different-2 click listener for all ...

Comment: The Problem is not about click events. Displaying two views in one Item and separating them with span count.

Comment: can u elaborate "two views in one Item" ?

Comment: yes, Just one RecyclerView and maintain to views one for parent and another for Child.

Comment: dude u r talking about recycler view feature where u set gridmanager on layoutmanager if i am not wrong .... ?

Comment: before calling the setAdaper to my Recyclerview like GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Comment: if u having same element then why u making two element ? by the way its ur problem now comes to ur problem if u use clicklistener what issue u face ?

Comment: I think `LinearLayoutManger` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your code, it might help to get the bug. However, as you have no grid like structure so instead of using GridLayoutManager, use LinearLayoutManager.

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);

Then bind your recyclerview with the layout manager.

This will work perfectly.